# Any way to know if calling method should Dispose the object returned by called method

Tags: c#, dispose, static-code-analysis

Is there any way to mark a method so that code analysis or build with give error message to dispose the object returned by method. for e.g. in the following method.

```
  private void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Brush sb = GetBlackBrush();
    }

    Brush GetBlackBrush()
    {
        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        return sb;
    }
```

whenever any method called GetBlackBrush, while building the solution in VS2010, i should get a code analysis warning or build error or build warning to indicate that i need to dispose Brush object. I want i should get some indication in chart1_Click() method to dispose brush object.

This is just a sample code,i know we should be using **"Using"** but here whats the solution.

There is a CA2213 code analysis warning but that is not getting called for this particular example.

Comment: You really dont want to dispose it immediately, do you?

Comment: Code analysis can't tell in that case whether you need to dispose the object or not. The method returns the object, which normally means it should _not_ be disposed, because you are handing it to some other code. So in your example, you should _not_ be using `using`.

In general, code analysis does a good job of identifying objects which are not disposed and which _don't_ leave the method.

Do you have a more plausible example where code analysis doesn't catch a genuine mistake?

Comment: this is a genuine example, code analysis doesnt give any error if you use this method GetBlackBrush() in any other method. code analysis doesnt give the error.

Comment: Please post exactly the code you wrote that uses GetBlackBrush and does not cause a warning in the code analysis.

Comment: Why would you expect CA2213 = "Disposable fields should be disposed" for this sample?  It doesn't include any diposable fields, only disposable local references.  I would expect to see CA2000 = "Dispose objects before losing scope" on the chart1_Click method though.

Answer (score 0):

CA2000 warning is something you might be after, see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289(v=vs.100).aspx):

> If a disposable object is not explicitly disposed before all
>   references to it are out of scope, the object will be disposed at some
>   indeterminate time when the garbage collector runs the finalizer of
>   the object. Because an exceptional event might occur that will prevent
>   the finalizer of the object from running, the object should be
>   explicitly disposed instead.

Not sure if you can mark it as error but it should pick it up.
You might want to enable also [CA2213](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182328.aspx)

Comment: You are correct with CA2213 but just try this exampl, I am not getting the CA2213 after running code analysis.

Comment: I've just checked it and in one case (in the same class) it's showing warning and in the other ( IDisposable created outside class) it's not. I'm using VS2013

Answer (score 0):

There are no particular conventions for indicating which methods transfer ownership of `IDisposable` objects and the Framework itself is rather inconsistent in that regard.  If a method creates and returns a reference to a new `SolidBrush` without retaining a copy of that reference, then the recipient of that brush should dispose it.  If instead the method had done something like:

```
WeakReference<Brush> myBrush = new WeakReference<Brush>(); // Field of class hosting method

Brush GetBlackBrush()
{
  Brush ret = myBrush.Target;
  if (ret == null)
  {
    ret = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    myBrush.Target = ret;
  }
}
```

then correctness would dictate that the recipient *not* call `Dispose` on the object it received [the use of the weak reference would ensure that there would at any moment in time the above code would only leak be a single extra `SolidBrush` object; if the caller abandons the instance without disposing it, then generally either the GC won't have noticed that the instance was abandoned (in which case the next caller will receive the same one), or it will have already cleaned it up.  In either case, no more than abandoned one brush instance would exist at a time.  Further, calling `Dispose` on a brush instance while `myBrush` held a reference to it would sabotage the next caller of `GetBlackBrush()`.